# In java, how to wait on multiple `Conditions` until any one of them is signaled

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose an elevator simulation program, visitors about to take a ride are to wait until any one of the elevator doors opens. i.e. I want to wait on multiple `Conditions` until any one of them is signaled.

Actually, it doesn't have to be `Conditions`, other approaches that can fulfill my need is welcome.

How can this be done in Java?

Comment: What you describe is actually a queue. Use some BlockingQueue and put the finished task there.

Comment: @bestess You are right! However, you commented but didn't answer. So that I didn't notice it until now. What a pity. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) does the job you need. You would instantiate the latch with a count of 1:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

and then share it between your threads. All the threads that wait for the doors to open will do `latch.await()`. This method will not return until another thread calls `latch.countDown()`.

Comment: It seems `CyclicBarrier`, the repeated version of `CountDownLatch`, is what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [Observer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html). You will still have to handle treading issues but with Observer you at least have an easy way for the simulator to know when a door opens (triggers an event)

Comment: Any number of events can trigger the one Condition your thread is waiting for. i.e. the anyLiftAvailable condition.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does the job! But this approach completely reverse the way things are done. I won't try this unless no other solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a set of conditions, I'd use a `BlockingQueue<Door>`, (`Door` is an enum of the doors in the lift) where threads which want to use a door call `take()` on the queue, and threads which are opening a door call `put(Door.ONE)`. and then uses `drainTo` to remove any other open doors (presumably there's another mechanism to tell the door opening threads that the lift has left and that they can't open any more doors).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `Lock` protects shared state and `Condition` is used to wait for particular condition on that state.

But in your task you actually have two sets of orthogonal states - states of elevators and states of floors. It means that if you want to use `Lock`/`Condition` primitives to work with this task, you need to create separate locks and conditions for these states.

That is, when elevator arrives at the floor, it acquires its own lock and a lock of the floor, and then signals a condition associated with the floor, so that visitors waiting on the floor are awakened. Also pay attention on lock ordering to avoid deadlocks in this scheme.

Comment: I think the question was, how to wait for any of two Condition's.

Answer (score 0):

`Condition` is an unfortunate name, IMO.  Another way to think of `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` is as a *signal*.  So another way to think of your problem is that you have 1 "condition": a door is opened.  And whenever any of your elevator doors opens, you signal the generic "door is opened" condition.  Once the waiting thread is awake it will need to find which one is open (or find and select one if multiple are open).